# Selenium not fully downloading files

Tags: python, macos, file, selenium, download

I have set up a webscraper with beautifulsoup, selenium(chrome), and python.

It is pretty simple, beautifulsoup parses a page full of links, and selenium follows those links 1 at a time. Selenium finds a specific download link on each page and clicks it, starting a download. I would use beautifulsoup with this, but if I do not use a browser which clicks the link, it will send me to a page with a captcha.

Anyways, when selenium starts downloading the files, and the progess shows at the bottom of the screen with chrome. But, after a seemingly random amount of time, it says that the file is completely downloaded after only seconds before it was halfway done. There could be a 8 mb file, it only downloads 500 kb and then says it is finished. I don't know why it won't fully download the files, does somebody know a way to wait for it to actually fully download the file? Is there a limit to how many files are able to be downloaded at once? Because I am downloading quite a few files.

I have no clue what to do here, I hope someone can shed some light.

Comment: It can be that you don't need selenium here. May be passing an appropriate header (like User-Agent, pretending to be a browser) will help. Without the code it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need `selenium` here.

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is perfectly enough. Just set the `User-Agent`, `Host` and `Referer` headers properly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'url here'

def download_file(url, filename, headers):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
            if chunk:
                f.write(chunk)
                f.flush()

# get link and file name
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
a = soup.find('td', text='Download:').next_sibling.a
link = a.get('href')
filename = a.text + '.pdf'

# download file
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36',
    'Host': 'filepi.com',  # host could be extracted from the link
    'Referer': URL
}
download_file(link, filename, headers)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly, I will now integrate this into the code I currently have. I actually hadn't heard of requests before, so I will probably spend the next few days figuring it out. I am very glad that I didn't have to use selenium for this project, and I wonder why it wouldn't fully download the files.